# ORA-01403: No Data found?

Tags: oracle, plsql

when i try this PL/SQL to execute i have the error Oracle PL/SQL - ORA-01403 "No data found" in first select in for loop

```
declare

    CURSOR
        tempRow IS SELECT t2.*
                   FROM TABLE2 t2
                            JOIN TABLE3 t3 on t3.ID = t2.ID_FB;
    updateId integer;
    B        TABLE1.A%TYPE;

BEGIN

    FOR item IN tempRow
        LOOP
            select t1.A, t1.ID
            into B, updateId
            from TABLE2 t2
                     JOIN TABLE1 t1 on t2.ID = t1.ID_R
            WHERE t2.ID = item.ID;
            -- more conditions

--- more code
            dbms_output.put_line(B);
        END LOOP;
END;
```

i can't found the wrong in the statement.

can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

It says that for `ID` (in tempRow cursor), which is acquired via join of `table2` and `table3`, no rows exist in `table1` which is joined to `table2` in `select` statement within the cursor `FOR` loop.

To check it, include additional (nested) `begin-exception-end` block and display such a value, e.g.

```
BEGIN
   FOR item IN temprow
   LOOP
      BEGIN
         SELECT t1.a, t1.id
           INTO b, updateid
           FROM table2 t2 JOIN table1 t1 ON t2.id = t1.id_r
          WHERE t2.id = item.id;

         -- more conditions

         --- more code
         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (b);
      EXCEPTION
         WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
         THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('error on ID = ' || item.id);
      END;
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Then decide what to do; will you handle it somehow, ignore it, fix `WHERE` clause(s), ...